# Spring security authorization check not working

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have the following.

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class RetailerSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
                .csrf().ignoringAntMatchers("/login/**")
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/login", "/login/reset", "/resources/**", "/balance/getResult/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()
                .antMatchers("/retailers/**", "/balance/**").access("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
                .antMatchers("/tellers/**", "/tellers").hasAnyAuthority("PRIMARY")
                .antMatchers("/sell/**", "/sell").hasAnyAuthority("TELLER")
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .successForwardUrl("/login/success")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .permitAll();

    }
}
```

I've also tried a bunch of other permutations, none of it seems to work. I've checked if this part of the code  is executed, it does and goes through with no errors.

**EDIT**

Forgot to mention, all url are not accessible by an authenticated user. But any authenticated user can hit all urls. E.g logged in as `PRIMARY`, I can hit `/sell` and `/retailers/create` which shouldn't happen.

I'm running out of things to try. Emm... I RAN OUT already. What should I check?

Comment: What is the hit url ?

Comment: @sunkuet02 updated the question. You can take `/sell` as an example.

Comment: @sunkuet02 Added `csrf().disable()` and still the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Weird, but moving `anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()` before authority setup fixed it. Finally it looks like this

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class RetailerSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
                .csrf().ignoringAntMatchers("/login/**")
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/login", "/login/reset", "/resources/**", "/balance/getResult/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/retailers/**", "/balance/**").access("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
                .antMatchers("/tellers/**", "/tellers").hasAnyAuthority("PRIMARY")
                .antMatchers("/sell/**", "/sell").hasAnyAuthority("TELLER")
                .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .successForwardUrl("/login/success")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .permitAll();

    }
}
```

Comment: You Kno I can't before 2days